# How to use waitForJs with Codeception and Selenium2

Tags: php, selenium, codeception

I am new to Codeception and Selenium and am having trouble testing with Ajax calls. I want to use the waitForJS method but it returns the following error:

```
RuntimeException: Call to undefined method WebGuy::waitForJS
```

My yml file looks like this:

```
class_name: WebGuy
  modules:
     enabled: [Selenium2]
     config:
         Selenium2:
             url: 'http://dev/'
             browser: firefox
             capabilities:
                 unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
```

I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found that I hadn't run the rebuild command after changing the yml file. All working now.

Comment: Which you have done by typing something along the lines of `php codecept.phar build` right?